# Circular convolution in python

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a way with Python to perform circular convolution between two 1D arrays,
like with Matlab function `cconv`?
I tried `numpy.convolve` but it isn't the same, and I can’t find an equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this command : [scipy.ndimage.filters.convolve1d](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.convolve1d.html#scipy.ndimage.filters.convolve1d)

You have an option which is named `mode`and you can write `mode = wrap`

With that, you get periodic boundary conditions as padding for the convolution

For example :

```
result = scipy.ndimage.convolve(image,kernel,mode='wrap')

import numpy as np
image = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0, 1],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0]])
kernel = np.array([[1, 1, 1],
                    [1, 1, 1],
                    [1, 1, 1]])
from scipy.ndimage import convolve
convolve(image, kernel, mode='wrap')
array([[1, 0, 1, 1],   
       [1, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 1]])
```