# How to do N-Point circular convolution for 1D signal with numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I want a circular convolution function where I can set the number `N` as I like.

All examples I looked at like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35474078/python-1d-array-circular-convolution) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37150672/circular-convolution-in-python) assume that full padding is required but that not what I want.

I want to have the result for different values of `N`

- so input would `N` and and two different arrays of values
- the output should be the N point convolved signal

Here is the formula for circular convolution. Sub `N` can be seen as the modulo operation.

[image]

> [taken from this basic introduction](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/digital_signal_processing/dsp_discrete_fourier_transform_circular_convolution.htm)

##### update for possible solution

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66709258/14653849) is a suitable solution when the array `a` is piled accordingly to the different cases of `N`.

When I find time I will post a complete answer, meanwhile feel free to do so.

Thanks to @André pointing this out in the comments!

#### examples for input/output [from here](https://signalprocessingsystems.netlify.app/disciplines/discrete/discretesignalprocessing_transforms_dft_convolution/)

##### N = 4

[image]

##### N = 7 with zero padding

[image]

Comment: you should provide practical examples of what you expect (sample input(s)/output(s))

Comment: I tried to specify do you need more concrete examples?

Comment: I have added a link which shows the procdure for different value of `N`

Comment: Please, it's best if you provide an explicit example here in the question.

Comment: okay done, sorry for the vague question

Comment: @OuttaSpaceTime I think the other commenters expect some explicit numerical values, e.g. by definition of `x1=np.array([1,2,3,4])` , `x2=...`, `expected_result=...` . Having some code to start with makes it a bit easier to reproduce and begin working on your problem, just as well as confirming that the answer is actually correct.

Comment: I see that is a good point

Comment: @André I think it might be a solution if we change how the array `a` is tiled. I think in the case `N => L > P` we have to zero pad `a` and in the other `a` will be tiled from a different index. Thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that this should work:

```
def conv(x1, x2, N):
    n, m = np.ogrid[:N, :N]
    return (x1[:N] * x2[(n - m) % N]).sum(axis=1)
```

This is a direct translation of the formula posted in the question:

[image]

To implement this formula, first we compute an array of indices used by x₂. This is done using the code

```
n, m = np.ogrid[:N, :N]
indices = (n - m) % N
```

For example, for `N=5`, the array `indices` is:

```
[[0 4 3 2 1]
 [1 0 4 3 2]
 [2 1 0 4 3]
 [3 2 1 0 4]
 [4 3 2 1 0]]
```

The entry in the i-th row and j-th column is `(i-j) % N`. Then,
`x2[indices]` creates an array consisting of elements of `x2` corresponding to these indices. It remains to multiply each row of this array by the first `N` elements of `x1` and take the sum of each row:

```
(x1[:N] * x2[indices]).sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: cool thanks! would you mind adding some details what the exact parts of your function are doing?

Comment: @OuttaSpaceTime I added some explanations.

Comment: pretty neat thanks, +1000

Comment: The code gives errors when I try with `h = np.array([1, 0, 2, 1]), x = np.array([1, -1, 0, 2, -2, -1])` and `N = len(h) + len(x) - 1`: `IndexError: index 8 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 6`

Comment: The right zero padding is probably missing, when the signal have not the same length proper zero padding is required

Comment: @OuttaSpaceTime The formula for the convolution that you posted assumes that both arrays have at least N elements. What to do when this is not true will depend on what you are trying to accomplish - you can pad the arrays with some values, you can repeat their values, you can declare that the operation cannot be performed etc. It is a decision how to extend the formula to other cases. Once you do it, then you can modify the code accordingly.